# Prove that $a_{n}\to L$ as $n\to\infty$ iff $\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_{n}) = \liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_{n}) = L$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose that $(a_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a bounded sequence and that $L\in\textbf{R}$. Then $a_{n}\to L$ as $n\to\infty$ if and only if
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_{n}) = \liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_{n}) = L
\end{align*}

**Proof**

I am mainly interested in the direction $(\Rightarrow)$.

The book which I am reading provides the following argument:

"Suppose that $a_{n}\to L$ as $n\to\infty$. Then if $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $n_{0}$ s.t. $L - \varepsilon/2 < a_{n} < L + \varepsilon/2$ for $n\geq n_{0}$.

Thus $L - \varepsilon < M_{n} < L + \varepsilon$ for $n\geq n_{0}$ so that $M_{n}\to L$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus $\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_{n}) = L$.

Similar reasoning applies to the $\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_{n})$."

Here, the notation $M_{n}$ means $\sup\{a_{j}:(j\in\textbf{N})\wedge(j\geq n)\}$.

**My question**

I did not understand why $L - \varepsilon/2 < a_{n} < L + \varepsilon/2$ implies that $L - \varepsilon < M_{n} < L + \varepsilon$.

Could someone help me interpreting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $ k \geq n_0$, we have
$L-\epsilon/2 < a_k < L+ \epsilon/2$.

So for all $ n \geq n_0$
$$
L-\epsilon/2 \leq \sup_{k \geq n} a_k \leq L+ \epsilon/2
$$
and thus

$$
L-\epsilon < M_n < L+ \epsilon.
$$

Note how the strict inequalities become large inequalities when taking the supremum.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! I had forgotten about this property